# Solve $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-cx^2}\sin(sx)dx $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration

How to prove that $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-cx^2}\sin(sx)dx = 0,$$ where $c>0$?

Answer (score 3):

The function inside the integral is an odd function, So the integral is zero.